# How to transfer all my funds to another wallet

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info

i"m a blockchain wallet user with multiple wallets for different businesses but i would like to centralize all my funds to one wallet so i want to know if it is possible to transfer all the funds from the other blockchain wallets to the central one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Make transactions sending all of your coins from each wallet to one or more addresses in your central wallet. Note that this will require you to pay transaction fees. There is no way to move coins without making a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

1. Decide which wallet you're going to store your consolidated fund(s) on (hint: depending on amount check into hardware wallets or generate an offline paper wallet) (link: https://bitcoinpaperwallet.com/)
2. Generate a fresh address on wallet from 1
3. Go through each wallet client and send your coins to a fresh btc address generated in step 2